# error message - "No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8" - ecb package

Tags: r

I want to make use of the "get data" function from the ecb package to directly load data into a dataframe. The data was simply accesible the whole via the following code

```
 library(ecb)
    deposits_nfcs_FR <- get_data("MIR.M.FR.B.L21.A.R.A.2250.EUR.N")
```

However, since today I obtain the following error message

```
No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
Error in check_status(req) : HTTP failure: 502
<html lang="en"><head><title>European Central Bank</title><style type="text/css"> body{ font-family: "Droid Sans", sans-serif; margin:0; padding:0; background-color: #9099ab; text-align: center; } h1{  font-size:38px; font-weight: normal; color:#003299; }  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) { h1{ font-size: 30px; } }  p { font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #333; margin-bottom: 20px; }  p.signature{ font-style: italic; color:#DF0101; }  .centredFrame { margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; width: 70%;   } .content{ margin-top:40px; padding:40px; background-color: #fff; border:1px solid #CDE3E0; -moz-border-radius: 20px; border-radius: 20px; } </style><link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></head><body><div class="centredFrame"><div class="content"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAACACAYAAACx1FRUAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JQAAgIMAAPn/AACA6QAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF2+SX8VG
```

Does anybody has any idea?
The solution must be straightforward since I haven't changed anything with in my code.

Many thanks in advance and best regards!